# Problems with pyGTrends module - PYTHON

Tags: python

It is now 6 months that I use the module
pyGTrends to download data about search queries.

From a couple of days, it appears that the pyGTrends module does not 
work anymore, in detail the error produced is:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d_queries.py", line 41, in <module>
    print queryReport.csv()[:100]
  File "/----/----/Desktop/pangea/queries_v1/pyGTrends.py", line 107, in csv
    raise Exception("Could not find requested section")
Exception: Could not find requested section
```

---

Adding some "print" command in the module pyGTrends.py 
when I print  "self.raw_data" I obtain

---

```
??You must be signed in to export data from Google Trends.
```

---

I made some checks, for instance Google does not have changed the syntax of the  URL to get the csv since
if I manually insert in the browser the output of the line

```
self.raw_data = self.opener.open('http://www.google.com/trends/viz?' + params).read()
```

(once manually performed the login in Google Trends)
I can regularly access the csv.

1-Are there other users who can confirm similar problems in the usage of pyGTrends?

2-I was wondering if the problem can be linked 
to the login procedure which perhaps has been changed by google (it is only a hypothesis,
I do not have any information about this).
In that case, which changes should be done in the code of pyGTrends?

Answer (score 1):

Google had changed its authentication url.  I pushed a fix to the github repository:
https://github.com/suryasev/unofficial-google-trends-api

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how old is that fix, but it is not working. I figure out that there is a problem with the pattern matching the GALX cookie. The pattern should be changed in

```
galx = re.compile('<input type="hidden"(.*?)name="GALX"(.*?)value="(?P<galx> ... ', re.DOTALL)
```

However, this doesn't seem to solve my problems as I still get the error that the requested section cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent version (9 months old), appears to be at:
https://bitbucket.org/mattreid9956/google-trend-api/overview

I have not tested it.  SirC, if you have found a different solution, perhaps you could comment on it?